# How to enable automatic routing in Netflix/Zuul and Netflix/Ribbon with discovery information from Netflix/Eureka Service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I'm quite new in things with the netflix cloud Microservice architecture.

There are three Microservices running in my Network:

- Zuul/Ribbon Service: localhost:8765

  `Application.yml:
    ===============
    eureka:
     client:
      serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/`
- Eureka Service: localhost:8761
- RentCarService: localhost:8888

Now, my request is: **localhost:8765/RentCarService/getAllAvailableCars**

This request should automatically routed forward to the right Microservice (RentCarService with Port 8888) like **localhost:8888/getAllAvailableCars**

I have seen much tutorials and the most of them are forwarding the requests programmatically like in this tutorial:

[Microservice discovery with spring boot and eureka](http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/microservice-discovery-with-spring-boot-and-eureka/)

[Or here by a method called getServiceURL](https://github.com/callistaenterprise/blog-microservices/blob/B1/microservices/composite/product-composite-service/src/main/java/se/callista/microservices/composite/product/service/Util.java)

Do i have to code the forwarding by my own or is **this possible automatically by Ribbon**?

Beste regards
lars

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as automatic routing till now for atleast we need to declare [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) in your yml file which will handle routing.

In your application.yml add these line

```
 zuul:
  routes:
   users:
    path: /myusers/**
    serviceId: users_service
```

For ignoring any routing use ignoredServices property like

```
 zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
```

For more information please see this [this](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) link.

This will ignore all automatic routing of your services.

Hope this helps you out.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your comment! But this don't imply, that i'm offering a service called **users** ?

I think, maybe this is an oportunity?
https://github.com/jmnarloch/ribbon-discovery-filter-spring-cloud-starter

best regards,
lars

Comment: because, i don't want to describe service specific information in the application.yml. Every information about services should requested from the Eureka server. The Zuul server should route dynamically to the service which was registered in the Eureka server before.

Answer (score 0):

So far i got it working. My main problem was the different versions in the different microservies. Please be care about this!

Another think: I think an automatic routing (without any routing definition) is not possible. I had to write at least the name of microservice in the route definitions. The address resolution is be done by the Eureka server in that case.

Please correct me, if I'm wrong.